# Queues run X next jobs on queue of Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I'm looking information about run X next jobs on queue of Laravel.

On my app, only can run 10 on some queue (name_of_any_queue) per minute.

On doc only see this:

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=name_of_any_queue --once   Only process the next job on the queue
```

But this only run next job.

I've a task for running every minute command above.

It's possible? How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You cannot pass an argument to the queue to dictate how many items to process, other than one.
2. You cannot set a cron task to run less every minute.

Solution:

Use a loop and process `--once` 8 times within the loop.

Comment: Thanks. I think that its possible solution but I'm looking for others possible options.